# hadoop configuration: couldn load or find main class org.apache.hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop

i'm trying to learn hadoop, i'm following the course "the building blocks of hadoop" from pluralsight, i'm trying to run hadoop trough pseudo distributed mode, when i run the following command:

bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

i get the following output:

```
Application application_1530031734419_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1530031734419_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-06-26 16:50:21.067]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1530031734419_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
[2018-06-26 16:50:21.076]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster
Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
<name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
[2018-06-26 16:50:21.077]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster
Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
<name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
<value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://homestead:8088/cluster/app/application_1530031734419_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

i've tried to follow this log and also searched for similar problems, basically it seems the error is in some of the configuration files, so here they are:

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
                <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=~/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.0.3</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
                <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=~/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.0.3</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
                <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=~/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.0.3</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
                <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/,$MR2_CLASS</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh //since this file is quite big, i'm bringing just what i've changed from the default file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=~/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.0.3
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

plus: all processes from sbin/start-all.sh are running. The OS is ubuntu, but is running through a virtual machine on a windows 10 computer. hadoop version is 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

When it says

`${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}`

1) you need to guarantee that path is the same on every machine in the Hadoop cluster

2) The full path means without the `~/` in the path

Comment: If you're already using a VM, then Hortonworks or Cloudera (or finding Vagrant boxes on Github) would be better choices unless you want to learn to install Hadoop, not just use it

Comment: your answer and suggestion actually makes sense, but for me it's important to learn how to configure Hadoop, i updated my file replacing the ~/ with /home/vagrant, i ran sbin/stop-all and start all again, but i'm still getting the same error, what seems weird to me is that the pluralsight course and the hadoop tutorial only talk about the first property (fw.name), it seems it should work without the other 4, i'll keep searching for an answer, if i fail i will try to redo the steps with a different version of hadoop, as last option i may use a already configured VM. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Hmm. In my previous installations, I had exported values like `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` somewhere under `/etc/profile`, that way it would be picked up system-wide rather than from any property file